# Extract unique single commands from history

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, sort

I have created a file called histcopy.txt with the command history, 
(`history > histcopy.txt`). It look somewhat like this:

```
 1. l
 2. ls
 3. cat necopy.txt
 4. netstat
 5. cd | ls-l ; grep -i "3" histcopy.txt | echo
```

And I want to print out each unique command, this is the command I run so far:

```
awk '{print $2}' histcopy.txt | sort|uniq`
```

And the outcome of that is:

```
l
ls
cat
netstat
cd
```

But in the last line (`5. cd | ls-l ; grep -i "3" histcopy.txt | echo`), there are many commands that it ignores and only takes the first `cd`. How can I rewrite my current command so that it extracts them as well? So that from the 5th line it would also extract:

- `ls-l`
- `grep -i "3: histcopy.txt`
- `echo`

making of them separate items in the output list.

Comment: Add a concrete sample input and your desired output from that.

Comment: try - awk -F "^[0-9]+\." '{print $2}'

Comment: try `sed 's/^\s*\S*\s*//' histcopy.txt | tr '|' '\n' | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u` but this just helps bring out piped commands into newline and won't recognize command within command/process substitution and so on...

Comment: @Sundeep Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep Your example gave me what I wanted! But Would you like to explain what everything in it does? I'm eager to learn about this and understand what it is that I'm doing.

Comment: @kreqq_ the sed one removes initial space and history number associated with command, we don't need that... tr will change those characters to newline.. so `tr '|;' '\n'` will help for both pipelines and ; separated commands.. and awk prints first column which is then sorted uniquely.. or use `awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'` instead of awk+sort combo

Comment: Thanks for that @Sundeep! Helped med alot! One more question @Sundeep if you want and have the time. How can i get the set of command-names that started pipelines? Can I use that same command in somehow?

Comment: @kreqq_ can you elaborate? like how should the output look like?

Comment: @Sundeep The output should be the commands that start a pipeline, for example the (5th) command has a few commands that start a pipeline, like
cd and grep i think. I want it to print out those commands that start the pipelines :)

Comment: try `sed 's/^\s*\S*\s*//' histcopy.txt | tr ';' '\n' | grep -oP '^\s*\K\S+(?=.*\|)'`

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, deliver once again! Thanks alot for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat histcopy.txt 
 1 l
 2 ls
 3 cat necopy.txt
 4 netstat
 5 cd | ls -l ; grep -i "3" histcopy.txt | echo

$ sed 's/^\s*\S*\s*//' histcopy.txt | tr ';|' '\n' | awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'
l
ls
cat
netstat
cd
grep
echo
```

- `sed 's/^\s*\S*\s*//'` to remove initial space and number associated with command in `history` output
- `tr ';|' '\n'` replace `;` and `|` with newline characters. This will work for current problem statement, but won't help if there are commands inside substitutions, etc
- `awk '!seen[$1]++{print $1}'` unique commands

Similar logic implemented with `perl` alone

```
$ perl -lne 's/^\s*\S+//; (@a)= split/[;|]/; foreach (@a){($k) = /^\s*\K(\S+)/; print $k if !$seen{$k}++}' histcopy.txt 
l
ls
cat
netstat
cd
grep
echo
```

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, this Answer is very good! I'm new to unix forum, i'm usually in stack overflow so i dont have the requierd points to upvote your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\n|\\||;|\\$\\("}
     $1 ~ /^[0-9]+\./ {print $2; next}
     {print $1}' file | sort | uniq
```

**Explanation**: Tell awk that your record separator can be either a newline OR a "|", OR ";", OR "$(", that way piped, substituted or chained commands are split into records. Then check if your first field is a number followed by a dot, if so then you're at the beginning of a line, so print second field; otherwise, print the first field.